# jQuery popover wont load second time

Tags: jquery, popover

I am using this popover on my page: https://github.com/klaas4/jQuery.popover
I have multiple instances of the popover with different content and triggers. This is my JavaScript that says what should happen when i press a link

```
$(".addWorker").popover({
    title: "Worker",
    content: "Laddar..."
});

$(".addWorker").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).popover(
        'ajax',
        "/jobs/AddWorker?jobid=" + $(this).attr("id")
    ).popover('show');
});

$(".markAsFinished").popover({
    title: "Finished",
    content: "Laddar..."
});

$(".markAsFinished").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).popover(
```

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'popover' (repeated 3 times)
            'ajax',
            "/jobs/MarkAsFinished?jobid=" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-jobid") + "&userid=" + $(this).parent().parent().attr("data-userid")
        ).popover('show');
    });

Now this works great the first time i click a link, and the popover shows up. The content is loaded and presentet within the popover. But then when i want to open up another popover (presses another link), it get's stuck at "loading" and no content is loaded. The same link works great if i refresh the page. Chrome Developer Tools tells me the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'popover'
```

I have no idea how to solve this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: post it on jsfiddle and give us a link